# how to generate linked in Access token using Console application C#?

Tags: c#, console-application, token, linkedin-api

Team, Anyone can guide me how to generate Token for Linked in?

I am trying with developer account but i can see option for MVC not for Console application.

please anyone can help me to generate token using console application for linked in?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question, but the procedures to get access_token is well explained in linkedin documentation, just do as it says, no difference what platform you are using the procedure is the same 
you can read more about this [linkedin api documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?context=linkedin/marketing/context)